# How can you add an item to the right-click menu in nautilus (without Nautilus-Actions)?

Tags: nautilus

I'm trying to give my image uploader some kind of rightclick->upload functionality. Currently I use the nautilus-scripts folder, but that puts the menu entry behind an unapparent "Scripts" item.

I've tried looking it up but I can only find people referencing nautilus scripts or Nautilus Actions (which isn't what I want for packaging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Nautilus Extension as described here:

http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/extending-nautilus-context-menus-using-nautilus-actions-scripts-and-python-extensions/

> Nautilus is one of the most commonly used file manager for GNOME. One
>   of the reasons for its popularity is its extensible architecture that
>   allows developers to write scripts to customize it. Even if you are a
>   command line person, extending Nautilus will result in dramatic
>   increase in productivity. In this post, I will discuss the multiple
>   ways in which Nautilus can be extended and the relative merits in each
>   approach.
>
> The first step in extending Nautilus is to find the set of actions that are tedious (atleast not straightforward) – Tasks that need
>   additional clicks or switching to terminal to get completed. The next
>   step is to determine if there are command line tools available to
>   automate the task or the task can be completed by additional code –
>   Again since you are extending Nautilus, the task involved has to
>   relate to files or folders. For eg, opening a file as administrator is
>   a "relevant" task but starting a nuclear war from Nautilus is not !
>
> Informally, it is easy to extend Nautilus if your task falls in the
>   following categories : Adding new entries in context menus (or in
>   toolbar) that involve selected files/folders or current folder, add
>   additional custom properties to files and display those details in
>   list view, modify the properties page to display additional tabs with
>   information etc. There are other possibilities but these are the most
>   common ones.
>
> If the above discussion sounds very abstract let us give some examples :
>
> 1. Open a terminal in the current folder or open the selected file as root.
> 2. Selecting a few audio files and adding them to Rhythmbox "Now Playing" queue.
> 3. Selecting a few files and sending them to thunderbird for attachment
> 4. Display IMDB details about the selected movie file in the property page etc.
>
> The above examples show a gradient of use cases in the order of
>   complexity. Some of them are so simple that they can automated using
>   simple means. Tasks like (4) are tricky and need powerful tools.
>   Selecting the right tool is important and we will discuss how to
>   select the best approach.
>
> Different Approaches to Customize Nautilus Context Menus Like
>   everything in Linux, there is always a variety of ways to customize
>   Nautilus ranging from simple to complex. In this post, we will discuss
>   the three most common approaches :
>
> 1. Using tools like nautilus-actions
> 2. Using Nautilus scripts
> 3. Using extensions written in nautilus-python
>
> As before, all my discussion will be focused on Ubuntu but it should
>   be relatively easy to apply to other Linux distributions.
>
> Customizing Nautilus context menu using  nautilus-actions This is
>   probably the easiest method. All you need to know is the shell command
>   or script to perform the task. Nautilus actions provides an intuitive
>   GUI to decide on the filters and the actions to be performed. This
>   approach works best if the following conditions are met :  a. the task
>   you want to be automated is easily translatable in command line  b.
>   the command line utility accepts the arguments in a relatively simple
>   form (eg space separate arguments etc)  c. The command line utility
>   depends only on information pertaining to the selected file/folder.
>
> To install the package, type the following at terminal (or install
>   this package from Synaptic) :
>
> ```
>  sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
> ```
>
> Once the package is installed it can be accessed at System ->
>   Preferences -> Nautilus Actions Configuration. I will only give a
>   basic discussion here as there is a decent tutorial on how to create a
>   new action at How To Add Custom Functionality To Nautilus.
>
> Let us take a simple example – If I right click on a folder , I want a
>   new menu which says, "Open Terminal Here" and when it is clicked, a
>   new terminal must be opened and the working directory of the terminal
>   must be the selected folder. The first step is to find if it can be
>   expressible in a "single" command. Find the name of the command to
>   invoke the terminal – it is called gnome-terminal. Read the man page
>   to find that it accepts an argument "–working-dir". When provided, it
>   starts the terminal in specified folder.
>
> Now start the Nautilus Action from System -> Preferences -> Nautilus
>   Actions Configuration . The steps are :  a. Create an action.  b. In
>   "Action" tab, give the action some name and select "Display item in
>   selection context menu". If you want it to be visible in the toolbar,
>   it can done too ! Select "Display item in toolbar" and choose some
>   icon.  c. In the command tab, give "gnome-terminal" as path and
>   parameters as "–working-directory=%d/%f". The %d and %f are special
>   codes that will be expanded when the command is invoked. To see other
>   special codes and what they mean, click on the "Legend" button.  d. In
>   "Conditions" tab, select "Only Folders".
>
> Now open a new Nautilus window , select a folder and right click.
>   Presto ! You will see a "Open Terminal Here" menu. Select it and you
>   will see a new terminal open with the selected folder as its current
>   directory !

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I needed to make a script for [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to compare modifications to folders/files.

I'm running on UbuntuGNOME 14.04, with gnome-shell 3.10 and Nautilus (Files) 3.10.1.

And I've done like this:

1. Open the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`.
2. (Optionally) Create a sub-folder to your script, which in my case was `Meld/`.
3. Create your `bash`, `perl` or `python` script (see the sample at the end of answer).
4. Make your script executable (right-click at script file > properties > permissions > mark the *execute* option)
5. To make sure that Nautilus will apply the changes, I've restarted Nautilus, running `nautilus -q; nautilus;` in a terminal.

And now, you can right-click on any folder/file to see the context menu *Scripts > my-script*.

Sample: `scripts/Meld/Compare_with_Meld`

```
#!/bin/bash    
meld $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Predefined Nautilus variables:

- `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`
   newline-delimited paths for selected files - only if local ( i.e. `/home/user/someFile`).
- `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS`
   newline-delimited URIs for selected files (i.e. `file:///home/user/someFile`).
- `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI`
   current location
- `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY`
   position and size of current window