# 'Scripts' menu not showing up while right clicking an empty area

Tags: nautilus

I have created a custom nautilus menu by adding my executable shell script inside the `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory. I can see my menu if I right click on any file/directory. But it is not showing up if I right click over any empty area. Help me resolve this issue.

**Note:** I don't wanna go for `nautilus-actions`. Need a solution other than that.

---

> *output of `apt-cache  policy nautilus`:*
>
> `nautilus:
>     Installed: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7
>     Candidate: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11
>     Version table:
>        1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 0
>           500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
>    *** 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 0
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>        1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8 0
>           500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages`

Comment: Did you give execution permissions to your script?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy nautilus`

Comment: @A.B. edited as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Man, in the [Official Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) site about Nautilus Scripts says:

> *"Scripts are invoked by **selecting a file or group of files**, and right-clicking with the mouse, to bring up a context menu".*

Scripts aren't invoked by clicking on the white space (current folder).

Additionally, you may want to see the section *"Wanted: Scripts and fixes"* at [g-scripts.sourceforge.net](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/) to **attest** that your need is a Gnome's feature-request, that is, the feature not exists, but it's already at *"Gnome-related wishlist"*.

I've studded a lot about Nautilus Scripts. I've made my [own script](https://askubuntu.com/a/672553/314158) too.

But, even though the Nautilus variable for "current location" exists, it's **not** possible to open *Scripts* menu from current folder (clicking on the white space)

Laters!